# Elasticsearch management tools like phpMyAdmin for mysql

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Is there any graphic management tools for Elasticsearch like phpMyAdmin for MySQL. I would like to be able to edit fields, chang mapping etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can suggest two other very handy tools, namely

- The [kopf plugin](https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf)
- The [head plugin](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head)

They both allow you to modify mappings, run REST queries, edit fields, create repository and snapshots, run content analysis, etc...

Give them a check and you'll see how handy they are.

Comment: Thank you a good man. The second one is the thing I was looking for.